# Scroll bar disappear when UL start from bottom

Tags: css, position, css-position

I want to have the Ul items start from the bottom, and when hit the container's height, then the scroll bar shows up.  It works if it starts from top, but fails when from bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/4c4crfhb/3/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<div class="big"></div>
<div class="parent">
    <ul>
        <li>Element #1</li>
        <li>Element #2</li>
        <li>Element #3</li>
        <li>Element #4</li>
        <li>Element #5</li>
        <li>Element #6</li>
        <li>Element #7</li>
        <li>Element #8</li>
        <li>Element #9</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
  background-color: gold;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#container ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 31px; */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#container {
  height: auto;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: box;
}

#container div{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: box;
}

#container div.big{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: darkcyan;
}
```

what is the problem?

What I want to achieve is like Slack's or Skype chat where the chat item starts from the bottom and move up, if overflow, then show the scroll bar.

Comment: you should check out my edited answer.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

When an element html is in absolute position and fixed at the bottom, then for the parent, it does not exceed. This is why scroll does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript could solve your issue like i did here:

```
var big = document.getElementById("big"); // OR SET HEIGHT OF PARENT USING CSS
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");

parent.style.height = big.offsetHeight + 'px'; // OR SET HEIGHT OF PARENT USING CSS
parent.scrollTop = parent.scrollHeight;
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4c4crfhb/7/

I've also edited your CSS. take a look at the fiddle ;)

EDIT:

> Here is an example with adding new Lines to the `<UL>` and setting the Scrollposition to the Bottom: http://jsfiddle.net/4c4crfhb/9/

Comment: It doesn't work if I want to start "growing" the 'li' item from the bottom of the container.   i.e.  just like Slack, when you start typing, it starts from the bottom and move to top.  :)

Comment: it's initial only... you have to build a function which is called everytime the content is changeing to set the scrollposition to the bottom (maybe using a timer too)... ;) every time you call ´parent.scrollTop = parent.scrollHeight;´ the scrollposition will be set to the bottom. ;)

Comment: I've edited my answer. take a look at the new fiddle ;)